# Parse multiple JSON files and load the data in android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

currently I am able to parse a json file and load the data in the view. But I need to parse multiple json files having different urls and load the images in my how. I am using an asynctask for this. Can I use the same async task for for all files. Or I ll pass the array of urls? Please suggest me the write way to parse json data from multiple urls.
I am passing urs as a string parameter to the task.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your logic , if you want to update the **UI** after loading each file then you can use several `AsyncTasks` and update the **UI** at the *postExec* method, or you can use just one `AsyncTask` if you only need a `ProgressBar` update using the publish method in the *doInBackground* method of the `AsyncTask`